# Looking for Bitcoin/Crypto payment processor that will split payments (pay multiple people from sale)

Tags: cryptography, payment

I'm looking for a crypto payment gateway that will allow me to accept payment for a product. It should support splitting the payment between multiple crypto wallets (multiple people).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [coinpayments.net](https://www.coinpayments.net/) or [bitpay.com](https://bitpay.com/)